# Translating address to function name

Tags: linux, gcc

Say I have an address acquired by `__builtin_return_address(0)`.
Sometime later I want to translate it to a coreesponding function name.

`There's dladdr(3)` which works only for dynamic libraries.
Is there any way to receive function of **any** symbol (maybe by libunwind, backrace_symbol() etc.)?

Comment: Do you care if it fails if the executable is stripped?

Comment: No, but in my case executable won't be stripped

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: @n.m. Implementing inhouse memory tracking, by overriding malloc/realloc/... Remember the caller address. Later want to display the leaks. Here I want to display caller function.

Comment: You may want to use http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/docs.html

Answer (score 1):

Compile all your code (and perhaps even some shared libraries that you use) with debug info (`-g`). Notice that [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) enables to use *both* `-g` and some optimization flag like `-O2`  (of course, in that case, the debug info is "approximate"). So you can compile code with `gcc -Wall -g -O2` etc....

Then use perhaps Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) which is included in recent versions of GCC.

BTW, `dladdr` or `backtrace_symbol` might also work (but I recommend using `libbacktrace` because it is parsing [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) info). And [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) does work on symbols from the executable itself. You may need to link your executable with `-rdynamic` flag.

Notice also that `static` symbols (notably  `static` functions) "don't really exist" in the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable (only *global* symbols are kept in it) so `dladdr` cannot give them. Be also aware of the [`visibility`](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) function [attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.htm) and [pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Visibility-Pragmas.html).

Comment: Looking at backtrace.h I see the API is busy with receiving back trace.
I don't need backtrace, but rather to translate a discreate address.
Can libtrace do this?

Comment: Did you try  `dladdr` (on some executable compiled with `-g -O2`)?

Comment: -ggdb3 without -O2.